# Desire HD Official Sense 3 update: Slate skin

Tags: htc-sense, htc-desire-hd, themes

I just updated my DHD to the official Sense 3 update.

Anyway, In Sense 2.1, I was using the sleek Slate skin. After updating, I went to "Personalize -> Skins" and chose "Get More"; Slate skin was not there. Also choosing different skins will produce "similar" looking skins (maybe with a little difference).

So, anyone knows how to get the old Slate skin back?

Answer (score 0):

Can you once try [Slate.apk](http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=577113&d=1303671939) from [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1048894) xda thread.

He has created/ported many skins.

Comment: Isn't that an extract from the HTC Hub? Meaning the original Sense 2.1 Slate?

Comment: I'm not sure on that.